# Daily new index at Elastic Search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a index time_series at Elastic.

```
PUT time_series
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3
  },
  "mappings": {
    "timeseries": {
      "properties": {
                "timestamp" : { 
                  "type" : "date",
                  "format": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                  },
                "value" : { "type" : "double" },
                "recordid" : { "type" : "integer" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From C# I feed the index with data.
I would like to have a daily new index 
like

- time_series_19050**2**
- time_series_19050**3**
- ...

So far I understand I need to set up a template.
I tried this, but I get a status = 400.

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["time_series*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "timeseries": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "host_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "_yyyyMMDD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How can I get a new index for each day?**

And do I need to adjust the the index at the C# code with the current date or does it goes automatically into the daily index?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem. What I did was create a console project(because I have other operations to do), create new index every time = 00:01:00. (Console porject have a trigger every 5minutes).
See this link, might help you https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-for-logging-how-to-configure-automatic-creation-of-the-new-index-every-day/19467/3